# Unable to covert audio to text nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, google-cloud-speech

I am trying to convert audio file to text using node js, I have got a reference link https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/speech, by using this link I am able to convert the sample files which include in it(viz., audio.raw, gs://gcs-test-data/vr.flac) from audio to text

But when I use the audio file from this [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/android-liveb4buy-merchantapp/liveb4buy_myshopify/59ccdcf01160d110000b9d60_Goldtouch%2BBluetooth%2BWireless%2BMini%2BKeyboard%2C%2BGTA-0033IKANB+(1).mp3) I unable to convert the audio to text, it shows an empty response. The response is `{ results: [] }`

Also I am aware of using these commands

```
 node recognize.js sync ./resources/audio.raw -e LINEAR16 -r 16000
 node recognize.js async-gcs gs://gcs-test-data/vr.flac -e FLAC -r 16000
 node recognize.js stream ./resources/audio.raw  -e LINEAR16 -r 16000
```

but, I don't know how to use the audio file from link to convert audio to text

Comment: Aravindh, could you add your code fully to the question?
which of the three examples you gave are not working? How do you "feed in" the audio stream you have?

Comment: Sure Koen, now I'm trying to use https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#search/speech/speech/v1beta1/speech.speech.syncrecognize I am able to convert a specific sample file("several tornadoes touchdown is a line of severe thunderstorms swept through Colorado on Sunday", i don't know how to insert an audio file stackoverflow) in any format but when i tried with different file it shows an empty response

Comment: I think you should store your audio file in a cloud bucket, and then use the link to that file in your async request?

Comment: Yes that 's how I am  doing, I will store my audio file to google cloud using the link as gs://bucket-name/file-name.wav, when i use syncrecognize it returns with empty response but when i use with asyncrecognize it returns with "name": "4705002481516695159", and then use this link GET https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/operations/4705002481516695159 it returns as {
 "name": "4705002481516695159",

 "done": true,
 "response": {
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1beta1.AsyncRecognizeResponse",
  "totalBilledTime": "30s"
 }
}

Comment: just include metadata in this comment because of not enough space  "metadata": {
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1beta1.AsyncRecognizeMetadata",
  "progressPercent": 100,
  "startTime": "2017-10-16T10:46:54.841148Z",
  "lastUpdateTime": "2017-10-16T10:47:00.571549Z"
 },

Comment: so you have to wait a bit, till the api has finished processing. So when you would call it again, you will see there is a response with the transcript

Comment: Great I've got a response but it doesn't have transcript field cache-control:  private
content-encoding:  gzip
content-length:  248
content-type:  application/json; charset=UTF-8
date:  Mon, 16 Oct 2017 10:48:56 GMT
server:  ESF
vary:  Origin, X-Origin, Referer
 
{
 "name": "4705002481516695159",
 "metadata": {
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1beta1.AsyncRecognizeMetadata",
  "progressPercent": 100,
  "startTime": "2017-10-16T10:46:54.841148Z",
  "lastUpdateTime": "2017-10-16T10:47:00.571549Z"
 },
 "done": true,

}

Comment: here i included response field  "response": {
  "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1beta1.AsyncRecognizeResponse",
  "totalBilledTime": "30s"
 }

Comment: I've got response with transcript field for which i already got answer ("several tornadoes touchdown is a line of severe thunderstorms swept through Colorado on Sunday") but for other audio file result field itself not present

Comment: Ok, Then check for sure if your audio file has the correct format as the api gives a null response when your encoding is incorrect. So maybe install audacity or sox and convert the file into a mono flac file.

Comment: yes I'm using .wav file format, and encoding as "FLAC", sampleRate is "44100" and languageCode is "en-US", still it gives as empty response

Comment: can you install sox (if you are on linux or so) and output what the play command is giving you in the terminal? This will help to know for sure if the file is correct. Next is to identify what your exact command is you are using to trigger the api?

Comment: Now installed sox in ubuntu and i identified that some files are playing in rhythmbox player but not in sox player, the file which plays in sox player will works fine in google speech api, but how can I play the other files which belongs to me (https://s3.amazonaws.com/android-liveb4buy-merchantapp/liveb4buy_myshopify/sample-audio-file.mp3)

Comment: you can convert files with sox easily by something like this:
sox input.mp3 output.flac  (just make sure your sox has been installed with flac support but I guess thats by default)

Comment: Thanks Koen, it works for me to convert mp3 file to flac using command (ffmpeg -i ./test35.mp3 ./output35.flac) and then convert audio to text, it can recognize the text in audio using the link (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/tree/master/speech)

Comment: ok. Added it as response to your answer. You can accept this then as an answer if you are happy with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Google Speech API it is important to make sure your audio format is correct. The API cannot be used with formats like mp3.

In order to use the api you can use a tool like sox or ffmpeg to convert to flac: 
 * Sox : `sox input_file.mp3 output.flac`
 * ffmpeg : `ffmpeg -i input_file.mp3 ./output.flac`

When a wrong format is used, the Google Speech API is coming back with an empty answer.

`{ results: [] }`